# Подсказка для индексов массива (свойств объекта) конфигов в IDE

Tags: массивы, ide, phpstorm, autocomplete, config

Использую PHPStorm, конфиги храню в JSON. Можно ли его научить делать autocomplete по моему массиву? Я могу хранить его в любом другом виде. В этом и состоит вопрос: как правильно, и как при этом получить автодополнение. Знаю, что JSON — не лучший вариант.

В массиве данные хранятся, а вот в IDE используются как объект. Конструкция вида  `opt()->field->login`, где  `opt()` возвращает декодированный JSON объект. Как мне хранить этот объект, чтобы IDE понимала его и делала автодополнение кода?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если у вашего массива чётко определённые индексы, то это объект, замаскированный под массив, а не массив.

Создайте класс и возвращайте типизированный объект. Чтобы тип, возвращаемый методом, определился, можете украсить метод соответствующими документирующими комментариями.

Для [создания типизированного объекта из JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/658469/deserializing-from-json-into-php-with-casting) придётся написать некоторое количество кода или воспользоваться библиотеками для сериализации. Например:

```
class Person
{
    public $firstName;
    public $lastName;

    public function __construct($firstName, $lastName)
    {
        $this->firstName = $firstName;
        $this->lastName = $lastName;
    }

    public static function createFromJson($jsonString)
    {
        $object = json_decode($jsonString);
        return new self($object->firstName, $object->lastName);
    }
}
```